# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder.SetPositiveButton

Tags: c#, android, android-alertdialog, xamarin

Momently i'm trying to create an Alert Dialog on Android application with C#. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder.SetPositiveButton(string, System.EventHandler<Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs>)' and `Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder.SetPositiveButton(string, Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener)' (CS0121) (App)
```

This is my code:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).SetTitle("Title").SetMessage("Message").setPositiveButton("OK", null);
alert.Show ();
return true;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cast `null` to Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your call to `.setPositiveButton("OK", null)` is ambiguous because the method has 2 overloads and your second parameter null can be interpreted as :

- `System.EventHandler<Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs>`
- or as a `Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener`

if you want to invoke the second overload, try this:

```
.setPositiveButton("OK", (Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener)null)
```